# when does getclassloader return null when using digest.getClassloader

Tags: java

I am having a this problem while using commons digester.

I have the jar in classpath set in my eclise.

Here is the code snippet.

```
Digester digester = new Digester();
System.out.println(digester.getClassLoader());
```

The above path returns me null in my machine whereas the same project with similar build path in another machine returns the classoader object.

Comment: If you have a short but complete program with *just* that as the contents of your `main` method, do you still see null?

Comment: hi Jon, it works perfectly fine if the program has only the above two statements in it

Comment: So have you got a simple program which fails? Try to cut your "big but broken" program down bit by bit until you can reproduce the failure in a simple way.